# awk command to merge the content of the same file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an input file with the following content

```
1 1
2 1
3 289
4 1
5 2 
0   Clear
1   Warning
2   Indeterminate
3   Minor
4   Major
5   Critical
```

I want to merge the first type of lines with the messages by the first column and obtain

```
  1 1 Warning
  2 1 Indeterminate
  3 289 Minor 
  4 1 Major
  5 2 Critical
```

Comment: what happened to `4 1`, and `5 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using join/sed, sed creates different views of the file for each part and join joins on the common field:

```
join <(sed '/^[0-9]* [0-9]* *$/!d' input) <(sed '/^[0-9]* [0-9]* *$/d' input)
```

*Gives:*

```
1 1 Warning
2 1 Indeterminate
3 289 Minor
4 1 Major
5 2  Critical
```

Comment: Not me either, I'm about to upvote @konsolebox though b/c i think his answer is best.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 in a { print $1, a[$1], $2; next } { a[$1] = $2 }' file
```

Output:

```
1 1 Warning
2 1 Indeterminate
3 289 Minor
4 1 Major
5 2 Critical
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=0}NR>6{n=1}n==0{a[$1]=$2}n==1{print $1,a[$1],$2}' file
```

or another way:

```
awk 'NR<=5{a[$1]=$2}$2~/[a-zA-z]+/ && $1>0 && $1<=5{print $1,a[$1],$2}' file
```